# Turn off rounded corner in EPPLUS ExcelChart

Tags: c#, wpf, epplus, epplus-4

Reading [Add RoundedCorners property to ExcelChart](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/pull/12/commits/6e228ce72a0e9a37ab54fcaa7c607715830fbe53) I guess EPPLUS adds rounded corner to ExcelChart by default. I like to get rid of the rounded corner and keep ExcelChart in clean squared corner, but can't seem to find a way to do so in EPPLUS (something that I can easily toggle in Excel itself).

I went through each property, and tried the following:

```
ExcelChart ec = ws.Drawings.AddChart("LineChart01", eChartType.LineMarkers);
ec.Title.Text = "LineChart01";
ec.Border.LineStyle = eLineStyle.Solid;
ec.Border.LineCap = eLineCap.Square;
ec.PlotArea.Border.LineCap = eLineCap.Square;
```

[image: EPPLUS Chart Rounded Corners]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the commit for adding the `RoundedCorners` property is tagged under release 4.1.1, it is in fact only included from 4.5 beta it seems.

From the [4.5.0.0 beta 1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/4.5.0-beta) release notes :

> 4.5.0.0 Beta 1
>   ...
>   * RoundedCorners property Add to ExcelChart

I am assuming you're using a stable version which explains why you don't see it. If you want to stick to a current stable version, you can in the meantime create a method to take out the rounded corners by modifying the xml directly.

For example using an extension method:

```
public static class ExcelChartExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Whether to show Rounded Corners or not for the border of the Excel Chart.
    /// </summary>
    public static void ShowRoundedCorners(this ExcelChart chart, bool show)
    {
        XmlElement roundedCornersElement = (XmlElement)chart.ChartXml.SelectSingleNode("c:chartSpace/c:roundedCorners", chart.WorkSheet.Drawings.NameSpaceManager);

        if (roundedCornersElement == null)
        {
            XmlElement chartSpaceElement = chart.ChartXml["c:chartSpace"];
            roundedCornersElement = chart.ChartXml.CreateElement("c:roundedCorners", chartSpaceElement.NamespaceURI);
            chartSpaceElement.AppendChild(roundedCornersElement);
        }

        roundedCornersElement.SetAttribute("val", Convert.ToInt32(show).ToString());
    }
}
```

and then apply to your ExcelChart

```
ec.ShowRoundedCorners(false);
```